# Vue dynamically add Component

Tags: html, vue.js, dynamic

For my Vue project i have a login component and a responsive overlay component.
I built it that way so i could load my responsive overlay component with the needed content using props.
To help you understand the structure, it looks like the following:

**Home.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import ResponsiveOverlay from '../components/responsiveOverlay.vue'
</script>

<template>
    <div class="overlayWrapper">
       <ResponsiveOverlay v-if='showDisplay' :switchContent='switchOverlayContent'></ResponsiveOverlay>
    </div>
</template>
```

**ResponsiveOverlay.vue**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import LoginOverlay from '../components/loginOverlay.vue'

    const props = defineProps({
        switchContent: String, 
})

</script>

<template>
    <div class="responsiveOverlayWrapper">
        <LoginOverlay v-if='switchContent == "login"'></LoginOverlay>
    </div>
</template>
```

**LoginOverlay.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>Login</h1>
</template>
```

SwitchOverlayContent is a string variable, that (as of now) is hardcoded to contain "login"

As you can see, i tried using v-if="showDisplay" with the ResponsiveOverlay in a hope i could just toggle the bound bool and it would show, which did not work, probably because the v-if is only ran when loading the page.
So what i would need is a solution where i could click a button which would then set switchOverlayContent dynamically to "login" and then display the ResponsiveOverlayContent.
How would i achieve said behaviour and also, is my strategy of having a component inside of a component viable?

Comment: Please use codesandbox.io or similar to show what you have so far. What you want to achieve is fairly simple using Vue but we have no way of knowing what's wrong with your code without a *runnable* [mcve].

Comment: @tao Hi, i edited the question to make it more understandable and reproducable. Could not get the whole component thing to work in codesandbox.io. Please have a look at the revised question. I am happy to provide even more details if needed

Comment: `switchOverlayContent` doesn't seem to be defined in Home.vue. You probably have multiple such errors. Just open up a new Vue3 template in codesandbox, copy/paste your components and your package.json. It doesn't have to work, but someone could take a look at what you've done and tell you why it's not working. What you posted here is not runnable.